# Excel Connect to SharePoint Online Document Library

Tags: office-365, excel

We have a number of people in the field who fill out fairly complex evaluation forms in excel. These forms are submitted to a document library in SharePoint Online

What I need to be able to do is report off these submitted excel files reading and consolidating specific data (they are all of a consistent format). There may be any number of excel sheets in the source document library

Previously I would have done this using VBA but I cannot find a way of connecting to a sharepoint online document library from excel vba - I am open to other options